# Spring data inject repository without explicit type

Tags: spring-data, autowired

I have a service that needs to use `Neo4jRepository` (regular repository provider by spring data).

```
public class SomeServiceBean<T>{

     @Autowired
     private Neo4jRepository<T,Long> Neo4jRepository;

}
```

This class will generate en error:

```
 expected single matching bean but found 2: systemUserRepository,systemClaimRepository
```

The problem is that `systemClaimRepository` and `systemUserRepository` is extending `Neo4jRepository<T,Long>` as a bean without implementation.
Spring see `systemClaimRepository` and `systemUserRepository` as  `Neo4jRepository<T,Long>`  because they are extending it.

Is there anyway to inject `Neo4jRepository<T,Long>`?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

No how should this work?

You have two beans that match the interface and Spring does not know which implementation to inject.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I'm coming with T, T should make the difference

Comment: No. Because Java generics are a compile time construct. They not there during runtime. https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure